# Show the "link from the web" textbox by default in new image uploader

Tags: feature-request, uploader

This is the new image uploader:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Why do I have to click "link from the web" to paste in a URL? This view (after clicking) could just be the default view.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: Guess they did it to make it consistent with the old design, where "from the web" was a different "tab".

Answer (score 2):

I agree; but so as not to confuse the users with the "link from the web" sentence without forewords, I'd propose to rephrase it like this (and obviously remove "cancel" button):

> [image]

Comment: "cancel" can be changed to "clear", for those too lazy to press backspace.

Comment: @Sha what about cmd-backspace? :)

Comment: huh?? what's that?

Comment: @Sha cmd-backspace will clean the whole field...

Comment: @Sha Oh wait, are you a windows user? ctrl-backspace then, I suppose.

Comment: In Windows it just delete whole words - in case of URL it would work, but only a few are aware of this magical feature. ;)

Comment: @Sha On mac, cmd-delete removes all the contents http://i.stack.imgur.com/tF2KG.gif, the word by word removal is for option-backspace